# Equation involving floor function:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given n a natural number, find $x$ (positive real number) such that:
$$  6\lfloor x \rfloor=n, $$ where $ \lfloor x \rfloor $ represents the value of the floor function in x.

Comment: Please don't vandalise posts! I have reverted your vandalising edit, leave it as it is now.

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts. Don't ever do that.

Comment: Did you miss the word `EVER` in a piece of advice from a fellow moderator??

Answer (score 4):

For $n>1$, a solution is
$$x=(n+1)^{1/n}.$$
To prove it, use induction to show that $n+1<2^n$ for all $n>1$.

Comment: @Imawesome No, the solutions are not unique.

Comment: @Imawesome There is no explicit formula for all solutions. Knowing there is one is enough. Then, you know that around each $x$ there is a small interval of points satisfying the equation.

Comment: @Imawesome This is the solution to $x^n-1=n$. One can note that if there is a solution, it solves $x^n-k=n$ for some $k$ so all solutions are of the form $(n+k)^{1/n}$. It's then simply a matter of checking the range on which $k \leq (n+k)^{1/n} < k+1$ which is where those solutions are valid.